# Blazor drag and drop: ondragleave firing when on drop, instead of ondrop

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, drag-and-drop, dom-events

i'm a noob trying to implement drag and drop in my blazor 8 hybrid application, but the ondrop event is not firing. Instead, ondragleave is fired when I release the mouse.

We have two tables:

Panel A -has-> Proxy

Panel B -has-> DataComponent

We can start a drag operation by dragging a Proxy or a Component. This passes the underlying data to Panel B, which manages a list of data rendered by Components

Drop should be allowed within Panel B, or on top of a Component in Panel B, allowing for reordering of elements.

As described above, the ondrop event of Panel B is never triggered, but ondragleave instead.

-I have set @ondragenter:preventDefault="true" and @ondragover:preventDefault="true" on all components.

-I was suggested to prevent rendering of the components since that could be causing the DOM tree to lose track of the Panel B instance during the drag operation, but I am not sure how to do this without breaking everything. By inspecting the elements on Edge, it seems that the panel is not actually being re-rendered, so I am at a loss about what to do.
I also implemented a Context menu but this should be irrelevant here.

Panel B:

```
<div id="-panel-wrapper">
    
    <div id="@DropZoneId"
         @onclick="Click"

         @ondragover:preventDefault="true"
         @ondrop="args => OnDrop(args)"

         @ondragenter="args => OnDragEnter(args)"
         @ondragleave="args => OnDragLeave(args)"

         @oncontextmenu:preventDefault="true"
         @oncontextmenu="args => ContextMenu(args)"
    >   

        @*  
            Iterate over the items in the  panel.
        *@        
        @for (int i = 0; i < _dataItems.Count; i++)
        {
            Data item = _dataItems[i];
           
            <div class="Data-row">

                <div class="row-index"> @(i + 1) </div>
                <div class="row-item">
                    <CascadingValue Value="@this">
                        @{  
                            // Generate a unique id for the component.
                            string id = "fic-" + i.ToString();
                        }

                        @* Render the data. *@
                        <DataComponent @ref="_reference" Id="@id"
                            Data="@item" ContextMenuCallback="ContextMenuInst"
                            @oncontextmenu:stopPropagation="true"
                        >
                        </DataComponent>
                        
                    </CascadingValue>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>

</div>
```

DataComponent :

```
<div class="@State.ContextClass()" id="@Id"
    draggable="@State.Draggable"
    @oncontextmenu:preventDefault="true"
    @oncontextmenu:stopPropagation="true"
    @oncontextmenu="args => OnContextMenu((args, this))"

    @ondragenter:preventDefault="true"
    @ondragover:preventDefault="true"

    @ondragstart="args => OnDragStart(args)"
    @ondragenter="args => OnDragEnter(args)"
    @ondragend="args => OnDragEnd(args)"
    
>
    @* @ondragenter="args => OnDragEnter(args)"
    @ondragleave="args => OnDragLeave(args)"
    @ondrop="args => OnDrop(args)" *@
</div>
```

The actual component event handlers are delegated to State objects.

Any tips are appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is hard to give an advice when we see no code.. You can see this example, where everything works as expected: https://github.com/tesar-tech/DragAndDropList

Comment: Well I dont know if this could have anything to do with it, but usualy one doesnt do
`@ondragover:preventDefault="true"` but rather `ondragover="event.preventDefault();"`

Comment: could you give is the DataComponent code/Parameters for reprodiction purposes

Comment: Actually give us some code for the Panel as well. like what are _references? or rather whats their type. If we cant reproduce it itll be harder for us to help you

Comment: @SMSTJ This actually solved the problem. In most components, the Blazor interface for the drag and drop API works as expected, but here JS interop was necessary. My guess is that it's likely due to Blazor losing track of the component reference. If you're still curious I can still post more of the code. Thanks for the suggestion; I feel incredibly stupid.

Comment: @Valen sure. Id be very interested to see the code/to see what the problem was and how you  fixed it ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @SMSTJ mentioned in a comment, doing
`ondragover="event.preventDefault();"`
instead of `@ondragover:preventDefault="true"` (or `@ondragover:preventDefault`) solved the problem.

In most components, the Blazor interface for the drag and drop API works as expected, but here JS interop was necessary. My guess is that it's likely due to Blazor losing track of the component reference.